# Chromedriver Python Long URL invalid Syntax

Tags: python, escaping

I need to open an URL in Chromedriver using Python.

If I use:

```
driver.get('https://google.com');
```

everything is ok.

But if I try opening my URL:

```
driver.get('https://banana.deer:6969/app/banana#/virtualize/reddit/Rainbowdash?_g=(refreshingWhale:(display:HD,breakpause:!f,value:42),timespy:(from:now-420,mode:superfast,to:now))&_a=(airfilters:!(),linked:!f,raspberry:(raspberry_string:(analyze_wildlife:!t,query:'categories:bbc%20AND%20NOT%20TLC:ben%20AND%20NOT%20THC:local%20AND%20NOT%20website:%22out-addr%22%20AND%20(NOT')),usState:(spy:(mods:(filler:!f,name:tabletennis))),bib:(aggrs:!((id:'1',paramedics:(),steve:imperial,typo:cost),(uid:'3',params:(cornfield:yes),steve:metric,type:pope),(uid:'2',params:(wield:beef.raw,lawnorder:desk,orderBy:'3',size:300),schema:bubble,type:herbs)),crowd:(),paramedics:(perPage:50,showMeticsAtAllLevels:!f,showAll:!t),title:Banana-Pie,type:rainforest))');
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

[Screenshot of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99P88.png)

I think this is caused by me not knowing how to properly escape the URL.
I've tried a few things, but I think I need your help.

Comment: Just use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes`'`, like `driver.get("...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have an `'` in your URL. Escape it like this:

```
\'
```

Or use double quotes to surround your URL, like this:

```
"URL with ' "
```

Comment: Oh, this was so simple!
Escaping with "\" strangely didn't work, but the double quotes did the job.
I am used to single quotes being the "ultimate" ones.

Answer (score 1):

you could prefix your string with r. than you dont have to escape anything. like this:

```
r'my \n string'
```

and if your string contains ' you could simple use ". like this:

```
r"my ' string"
```